# How to write unittests for Consumers in django channels?

Tags: python, django, django-channels, channel, django-unittest

A'm beginner in `django-channels`. I'm use `channels 2.3.1`. I have following code.

**main routing**

```
websocket_urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^ws/events/(?P<room_type>[^/]+)/(?P<room_id>[^/]+)/$', consumers.Consumer, name='core-consumer'),
]
```

**app routing**

```
application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'websocket': URLRouter(core.routing.websocket_urlpatterns),
})
```

**consumer**

```
class Consumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        room_type = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_type']
        room_id = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_id']
        self.room_group_name = f'{room_type}_{room_id}'

        await self.channel_layer.group_add(self.room_group_name, self.channel_name)
        await self.accept()

    async def receive(self, text_data = None, bytes_data = None):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json['message']

        await self.channel_layer.group_send(self.room_group_name,
            {'type': 'send_data', 'message': message}
        )

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(self.room_group_name, self.channel_name)

    async def send_data(self, event):
        message = event['message']
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'data': message
        }))

def send_event(channel='', message=''):
    channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
    asyncio.run(channel_layer.group_send(channel,
        {
            'type': 'send_data',
            'message': message
        }
    ))
```

**signal**

```
    def activate_notification(self):
        send_event(f'user_{self.id}',
                   {'message': f"Welcome back to one deeds!"})
```

How can I test every function inside a `consumer` using `unittest`?

I read this [documentation](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/testing.html) but nothing understand(

I want to run test with command `./manage.py test`

I tried testing this with `WebsocketCommunicator`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest a few things.

1) use the `channels.layers.InMemoryChannelLayer` layer.

2) use `pytest-asyncio` so that your test code can be `async` methods

```
@pytest.mark.django_db(transaction=True)
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_get():
   ....
```

to run these test you will then use `pytest`

3) use the `WebsocketCommunicator` check these [examples](https://github.com/hishnash/djangochannelsrestframework/blob/master/tests/test_consumer.py#L27).

Comment: How can I use single `WebsocketCommunicator` instance with different test functions?

Comment: @HamidRasti that is not possible.